# How to increment a number within a string format?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I tried to get the last inserted id, e.g.

```
$check = DB::table('items')
            ->where('id',$id)
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->first();
```

I get the last inserted id in this format

```
$date = new Carbon();
$date->format('ym');
//Date format
D-'year'001
```

How can i increment the number 001 to 002? If there is no record D17001 will be inserted else will catch the last inserted id and do increment on it.

Comment: Please include table data which shows what you are trying to do here.  Your question is unclear, at least to me.

Comment: Are you trying to create a unique ID based on the date (year, month) and a sequence number?

Comment: @Stefan yes, get last inserted and increment on it

Comment: This doesn't anwer your question directly, but you might be reinventing the wheel. Take a look at Laravel's [ORM Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) (scroll down to Primary Keys), which you could use to implement your Items and which takes care of unique IDs.